# How to make property of property in Protégé?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, object-property

I have a following problem to model in OWL using Protégé:

Multiple `Song`s could be performed in different `Performance`s. Each `Song` could be arranged by different `Arranger` in different `Performance`.

I already know how to relate a `Song` to a `Performance` using object property. Now, how to map a `Song`-`Performance` pair to an `Arranger`? (In relational database, I would call this as a "descriptive attribute" of a many-to-many `Song`-`Performance` relationship).

I know that I could use an annotation to an object property, but I would like to be able to infer something from this property. (For example: what `Song` has an `Arranger` arranged, and in which `Performance`?) As far as I know, I am not able to do inference from an annotation.

Comment: In other ontology editors, like TopBraid, you can reify a triple. That's not possible in Protégé, but you can achieve similar results with other means, using equivalent classes for example. If you provide more details of your data and what you want to achieve, it would be easier to propose a solution.

Comment: Standard reading material for this type of problem: [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/).

Comment: I'd say this could be considered a duplicate of [How can I express additional information (time, probability) about a relation in RDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923213/how-can-i-express-additional-information-time-probability-about-a-relation-in/33619395), which also includes some more possibilities outside of Protege (e.g., in Triple and Quad-Stores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to add properties of properties to model this scenario, although a property is an object (a uri) and therefore can include any property, not just annotation properties.  rdfs:subPropertyOf is a good example. Statement reification isn't necessary either.  It's a matter of creating an object that holds information about the song and performance.

Here is a model that represents an Arranger's relationship to a Song-Performance:

```
ex:SongPerformance a owl:Class .
ex:Arranger a owl:Class .
ex:arranged rdfs:domain ex:Arranger ;
    rdfs:range ex:SongPerformance .
ex:songPerformed rdfs:domain ex:SongPerformance ;
    rdfs:range ex:Arranger .
ex:performedIn rdfs:domain ex:SongPerformance ;
    rdfs:range ex:Arranger .
```

Given this list, an example instance is:

```
ex:Arranger-1 ex:arranged ex:SP1 .
ex:SP1 ex:performedIn ex:Performance_1 ;
    ex:songPerformed ex:Song1 .
```

Then you can find which songs has an arranger arranged in a given performance through the following SPARQl query:

```
SELECT ?arranger ?song ?performance
WHERE {
   ?arranger a ex:Arranger ;
       ex:arranged ?sp .
   ?sp ex:songPerformed ?song ;
      ex:performedIn ?performance .
}
```

Comment: "Statement reification isn't necessary either. It's a matter of creating an object that holds information about the song and performance."  That additional object is essentially a reification of the (implicit) higher-arity relation performance(arranger, performance, song).  But I agree that conceptually it may help to think of it as a completely new type of object that has a bunch of properties.

Comment: "Statement reification" is a specific kind of reification that is a statement about a statement, using `rdf:subject`, `rdf:predcate`, and `rdf:object`.  It's often defined as a member of `rdf:Statement`, hence the term "statement reification".  I was being clear that this kind of reification is not needed, contrary to one of the comments.

Comment: Yes, reification has a narrower specific technical usage in RDF, that's described in section [5.3 Reification Vocabulary](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-schema-20140225/#ch_reificationvocab) of the standard.  Reification (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(computer_science) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(knowledge_representation)) is also a more broadly applicable term where something that you can't directly talk about it abstracted into something that you can.

Comment: My point was just that whether one uses the RDF Reification vocabulary or not, the approach here is still reification (in the broad sense):  turning a statement (that can't be directly referenced) into something that can (an object about which statements can be made).

Comment: Understood.  Or one can just say it's a normal function of an object property (relationship), that references an object encapsulating the data.