# RDF/OWL Modelling an association with a time-span

Tags: rdf, data-modeling, owl, ontology, linked-data

I'm trying to come up with the best way to model temporally sensitive relationships within RDF.

Examples might be a "household" where there's a relationship between people living at a particular address - over the same period of time, or "workmates" describing people working in the same team, with some overlap between start-dates and end-dates within the team.

The concept I've come up with is an `AssociationInterval` a Class of object that has two primary object properties; `Association`, a group-like object that links a person to an address or team (or for another example, the installation of some hardware into an installation) and `Interval` which consists of both a start-date and end-date.

A person can then be linked to an `AssociationInterval` as a kind of placeholder for a compound object.

Is this something that makes sense? Or are there alternative patterns for modelling what must be a relatively common type of linked-data relationship?

Comment: Most likely, you have already read https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/33619395. I'd propose to express associations not between people, but between people and places (houses, teams etc), and then calculate associations between people. Perhaps you would be interested in Strabon, Badwolf etc.

Comment: See also http://blog.iandavis.com/2009/08/representing-time-in-rdf-part-1/ etc.

Comment: @StanislavKralin I had not read those previously but they definitely cover the ground very clearly. Yes it seems the method I’m looking at is the N-ary relationship one. I’d considered named graphs but intend to reserve their use for access-controls. Reification seems too complex to make a success of, but n-ary relationships seem awkward too.