# Can an ObjectProperty have a DatatypeProperty?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I'm trying to describe a graph using OWL. Let's say I want two classes `workshop` and `location`, and an edge between them `hasLocation`. Can I have a property on `hasLocation` which will denote the time that `workshop` occurred at `location`? I tried to define this using Protege but it seems one can only define properties on classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [annotations](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Annotations) or [punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Metamodeling).

However, annotation or data property will be a property of the `hasLocation` property *itself*, and not of its particular occurences. That is a key difference between RDF/OWL and LPG.

I'd suggest to use more or less [common](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33619395/7879193) modelling techniques. In Turtle:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/1226761/ontologies/2018/10/untitled-ontology-6#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

[ rdf:type owl:Ontology ] .

:Workshop rdf:type owl:Class .
:Location rdf:type owl:Class .
:SpatioTemporalExtent rdf:type owl:Class . 

:hasLocation rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
             rdfs:domain :SpatioTemporalExtent ;
             rdfs:range :Location .

:hasSpatioTemporalExtent rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                         rdfs:domain :Workshop ;
                         rdfs:range :SpatioTemporalExtent .

:hasTime rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
         rdfs:domain :SpatioTemporalExtent ;
         rdfs:range xsd:dateTime . 

:workshop1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Workshop ;
           :hasSpatioTemporalExtent :extent11 .    

:extent11 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :SpatioTemporalExtent ;
          :hasLocation :city1 ;
          :hasTime "2018-05-11T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime .

:city1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Location .
```

Alternatively, with anonymous individuals:

```
:workshop1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual , :Workshop ;
           :hasSpatioTemporalExtent [rdf:type :SpatioTemporalExtent ;
                                     :hasLocation :city1 ;
                                     :hasTime "2018-05-11T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime .
                                    ] .
```

> Do you know what is the reasoning behind not allowing properties on edges?

*RDF* means *Resource Description Framework*. It was initially intended for publishing data on the Web. Resources should have URIs (well, unless they are literals). Property occurences are not considered to be ontologically solid enough to have such strong identifiers. For example, their number is relatively large… In English, for comparison, one'd rather say *"I love you"* than *"I love-5 you"*.

Blank nodes (with their weak identifiers) in the predicate position could resolve this issue. So the question remains why blank nodes are not allowed in the predicate position (even for [Tim Berners-Lee](https://www.w3.org/2000/03/rdf-tracking/#rdf-bnode-predicates), though [not for Manu Sporny](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#relationship-to-rdf)).

I suppose that the reason is the desire to not leave first order ground for good, [bearing in mind](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-lbase-20031010/#using) 'natural' translation of the `a b c` triple  into FOL as something like `b(a,c)`. Then `[] b c` could be translated as `∃x b(x,c)`, but what about `a [] c`?

Comment: So if I understand correctly the solution you propose is to have a class called SpatioTemporalExtent and connect Workshop->SpatioTemporalExtent (with the datetime as a property)->Location? Is there no way to have the timestamp on an edge connecting workshop to location?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. And there is no way to have the timestamp on particular "edge" (it is more or less possible to have this timestamp on *all* edges constitueted by this property) in RDF or OWL. There are however RDF extensions like Blazegraph's RDF*, Google's Badwolf, Strabon's (?) stRDF etc.

Comment: And obviously you can make a datatype property a property of `Workshop`, if it is not the case that a workshop can occur at two different places at two different times  (e. g. in Rome today, in Paris tomorrow).

Comment: Do you know what is the reasoning behind not allowing properties on edges?

Comment: @Johnny this can be done in RDF via reification only. An alternative would be using a property graph or some non-standard extensions for RDF