# triple as subject

Tags: rdf, data-modeling, semantics

[PROV-O](https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/) allows representing provenance data. But it does this on the same level as any other data in the graph. What I mean is that I can assert that *Dave generated document #01221*, but that tells nothing about the actual provenience of the assertion itself. *What I need is to have assertions about other assertions* inside the same store.

Here is a real-world scenario: an external application acting on behalf of Dave records some facts in the store during a session that is part of a project which lasts three years. Of course, during this project many other sessions are affecting many other or even those facts. Provenance ontology allows me to assert what happened but only restricted to the nodes. I can't express which facts were created/modified/deleted during a specific session or activity... and finally get a timeline of the project actions with regards to the facts in the store.

I even want to go further: I want to store other information about the assertions, like reliability, expiration, and so on. These are neither related to the subject nor the object but to the link between them. In ER that would be an attribute of the relation.

This could be achieved by adding assertions about the assertions themselves. As far as I know, in RDF the triplets do not have any standalone identity, neither looks SPARQL to support something like this. Thus I don't see any chance to achieve what I want with RDF. But is there any other metamodel that has the flexibility of RDF and has support for my needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I express additional information (time, probability) about a relation in RDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923213/how-can-i-express-additional-information-time-probability-about-a-relation-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the RDF world, what you're talking about is referred to as *reification*.

One way of reifying RDF stays with the pure "triple" model, by identifying each assertion, and each element of each assertion, something like --

```
_:b1  rdf:type       rdf:Statement ;
      rdf:subject    :moon ;
      rdf:predicate  :consistsOf ;
      rdf:object     :greenCheese .
```

Another way is by shifting to a quad-model, typically using "named graphs" (which are supported by SPARQL).  A named graph may be made up of a single triple, and is often expressed as `{ Subject Predicate Object Graph }`, something like --

```
{ :moon :consistsOf :greenCheese _:b1 }
```

-- or as `{ Graph { Subject Predicate Object } }` something like --

```
{ _:b1 { :moon :consistsOf :greenCheese } }
```

With either of these, you can now say that `_:b1` was asserted by Joe on 1958-12-24, denied by Neil on 1969-07-21, etc.

There are various ways of collecting single-assertion graphs into multiple-assertion graphs -- for example, describing graph X as being made up of graphs M, N, O, and graph Y being made up of graphs X, P, Q -- such that you can describe (including providing provenance of) a single assertion, a collection of assertions, etc., as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Obviously I have missed this part. Just a reference for myself and others who are touching this topic and question: https://www.openlinksw.com/weblog/oerling/?id=1572

Comment: and another way, though non standard is called RDF* pushed by some people and supported by a few triple stores.

Comment: @AKSW could you direct me to some of such engines? Asterisc seem not to be google-friendly :(

Comment: well, Olaf Hartig has a Blog post regarding his work: http://blog.liu.se/olafhartig/2019/01/10/position-statement-rdf-star-and-sparql-star/ not sure if he'll update the supported triple stores. But as I said, the number of engines is pretty low which is not surprising given that neither RDF* nor SPARQL* is a W3C or some other standard. But I mean, in the end it's somewhat similar to using quads (http://www.websemanticsjournal.org/index.php/ps/article/view/168) with the difference being that the triple itself will be the identifier

Comment: @AKSW thank you anyway. I'll check those anyway to see what that concept brings to this world.

Answer (score 1):

The new **RDF***, or **RDF-star**, standardizes using any triple as a subject or an object by enclosing it in double angular brackets, for example:

```
<< :subj :pred :obj >> :pred2 :obj2
```

Support for this syntax already exists in some products, such as Apache Jena.

See [Olaf’s blog post](https://blog.liu.se/olafhartig/2019/01/10/position-statement-rdf-star-and-sparql-star/) and, for technical details, https://www.w3.org/2021/12/rdf-star.html.